# How to loop through json array to convert it into single values and list them?

Tags: php, json, foreach

i have fetched a json output for menus to be displayed in the webpage. 
I want to convert it into menus and sub menus. I have tried looping through it but it doesnt works.Please help me with this, thanks in advance.

```
$output = json_encode(array($menu_main_row['menu_name'] => $sub_menu));
```

Json Output:

```
{"Home":"[{\"Create\":\"create.php\"},{\"Edit\":\"edit.php\"}]"}
{"Projects":"[{\"My Projects\":\"myprojects.php\"},{\"My reports\":\"reports.php\"}]"}
```

This is the foreach loop which i used.

```
foreach($value as $main_menu_name=>$arr_val_sub)
{
    echo "<ul>";
    echo $main_menu_name;
    $val=json_decode($arr_val_sub);
    foreach ($val as $menu_name=>$menu_url)
    {
        echo $menu_name;
        echo "<br>";
        echo $menu_url;
    }
}
```

The main menu name is printing, but when i print the sub menu name and url it prints like 0 1 .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34871237/5678086

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed another step to dig into the json. `$menu_url` is another json to parse. Below code fixes it

```
foreach($value as $main_menu_name=>$arr_val_sub)
{
    echo "<ul>";
    echo $main_menu_name;
    $val=json_decode($arr_val_sub);

    foreach ($val as $menu_name=>$menu_url)
    {
        $submenu=new RecursiveArrayIterator($menu_url);

        foreach ($submenu as $submenu_name=>$submenu_url)
        {
          echo $submenu_name;
          echo "<br>";
          echo $submenu_url;
          echo "<br>";
        }
    }
}
```